# Including photos in a web map using qgis2web QGIS version 3.28.5

Tags: qgis-3, web-mapping, qgis2web, photos

I have included a field called photo in a point layer that I want to use in a web map to be published using qgis2web. The field widget type is attachment with the path stored relative to the project as the image attached.
Once the web map has been created (using the Leaflet option), do I need to adjust the coding of the html file or is there something wrong in how I have set up the field in QGIS?[image]

Comment: The relative path is not supported, select Attachment without changing anything else, in the feature field you will have to write the complete path of your image

Comment: Where do I write the complete path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relative path does not allow qgis2web to work correctly.
You must use an absolute path without changing the widget values.
Therefore in your layer field you will have to indicate the absolute path like in this image that show attribute table and widget setting.
[image]

Comment: Thanks that works

Comment: please set the answer as correct